# Making item selected of a ListView of ToggleButtons

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, listview

I have a ListView and each item has a toggle button. I want the to be able to toggle the button when the item is selected from the list, and untoggle when the item is deselected. It has to follow mvvm, so no code behind.

Here is my setup:

```
            <ListView x:Name="stampList"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding AllStampImages}">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>              
                    <DataTemplate>

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,2,0,0">
                            <ToggleButton Width="72" 
                                        Height="72"
                                        Command="{Binding StampSelectedCommand}"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

My problem is, when I hit the toggle button the item is not selected. Likewise, when I hit outside the toggle button (still within the boundaries of the listView item), the item is selected but the button is not toggled.

How do I tie the two together?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest way to do that is to have a collection of items provided by ViewModel or Model layer.

1. Each item should have a **IsSelected** boolean property :

```C#
class LineItem
{
    private bool isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return isSelected; }
        set { isSelected = value; }
    }
    private String label;
    public String Label
    {
        get { return label; }
        set { label = value; }
    }
}
```

2. There should be some binding to the model **IsSelected** property :

2.1 On the ListView.ItemTemplate

```XAML
<ListView x:Name="list1" SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListViewItemStyle1}" Margin="0,0,334,0">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ToggleButton Margin="5" Content="{Binding Label}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

2.2 On the ListViewItem Template

Create a Template with right clicking on the listview,

In the menu : "Edit additional templates/Edit generated Item container (Empty).

Fill with following code :"

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Grid x:Name="Bd">
                        <ContentPresenter  />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FF204080"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The trigger is based on Model IsSelected property.
The Grid is named Bd in order to change its background in the trigger.

Link to a full working demo : http://1drv.ms/1iyvPgt

**Note**

I trie to answer closely to the question .
But in my humble opinion, I would not use a ListView May be you have good reasons I gnore.

I 'd prefer to use an ItemsControl that is a listbox that doesn't allow to make a selection.

I'd put Toggle button, with custom Template to put a blue background if needed.
It would remove all the trigger stuff
, ...

Best coding

Answer (score 3):

You might have to bind the `Selector.IsSelected` property to you custome property. In this case to property of you toggle button.

Try something like:

```
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="{Binding [Value of your toggle button], Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```